# How to obtain the union of some images in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 5 images that are some maps that are calculated by multiplying a mask in an RGB image. Now, I need to find out the union of all regions in these maps. How can I calculate it in MATLAB? When I use `union` in Matlab it produces a vector, but my images are 512x512x3. Could you please tell me what should I do for this? For example I have 5 images like the following image and I want to calculate the union of all these images to find all parts that users select.

[image]

Comment: Your masks are logical (boolean) matrices of size 512x512? If so simply use an or to combine the masks. https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html

Comment: I'ts not clear what you mean with ***union***, ***maps*** and ***mask***.  I think this question needs more clarification and details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of two or more binary images (logical matrices) is computed using the element-wise logical OR operation (`|`):

```
mask = mask1 | mask2 | mask3;
```

For gray-value images use `max` instead:

```
mask = max(mask1, mask2);
mask = max(mask, mask3);
```

`union` is a function that computes the union of two sets, and is not applicable to images.

Comment: these images are color images. is it possible to use your solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: if I want to produce a heatmap that regions with more emphasis be warmer than other regions( with warmer color in the heatmap)  do you have any suggestions for this? for example if I add these masks to each other, some part of the final mask that exist in all masks has more intensity with comparison to other parts. how can I show this using heatmap or sth like this?

Comment: @david: Do you mean just adding the masks together? Pixels that are present in 4 masks will have a value of 4, pixels present in only one will have a value of 1, etc.

Comment: Thank you. yes, I know, but I like to know do you have any suggestion about producing the heatmap of the sum of all mask such that the places with the agreement of all maks is warmer than other parts.

Comment: `mask1 + mask2 + mask3` is all you need. You can display this as an image, then do `colormap(hot)` or something similar to give the display the desired colors.